# Как настроить аппаратное ускорение видео в Mint'е под VirtualBox'ом?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint

Собственно, установил Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon в VirtualBox.

При запуске Минт показывает такое предупреждение:

> **Запуск в режиме программного рендеринга**
>
> В настоящее время Cinnamon работает без аппаратного 
>   ускорения видео, поэтому может наблюдаться заметный 
>   рост нагрузки на процессор.
>
> Возможная проблема с драйверами, либо другие причины 
>   проблемы. Для достижения наилучших результатов, 
>   рекомендуется использовать только этот режим для 
>   устранения неполадок.

Что надо сделать, чтобы аппаратное ускорение заработало?

В настройках VirtualBox'а 3D-ускорение включено:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: `guest tools` внутри минта установил?

Comment: @donRumata, нет. А надо было?

Answer (score 1):

Установи виртуальные дрова для того, чтобы гостевая операционка работала максимально эффективно:

```
sudo aptitude install -y dkms intel-microcode iucode-tool virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
```

P.S. Да, делать это надо понятное дело внутри ОС виртуалбокса.

P.P.S. Если у тебя `AMD`, то пакет `intel-microcode` надо поменять на `amd64-microcode`.

Comment: Не помогло, к тому же, похоже, они там уже изначально стояли. http://pastebin.com/dKiz6QxX.

Comment: @Qwertiy, тогда скорее всего лучшего уже не будет. Только если не пробрасывать реальную видюху внутрь виртуалки. Но это очень сильное колдунство.