# Не меняется разрешение виртуальной машины

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Установил VirtualBox 4.3.12 и на нее поставил Ubuntu 14.04.5LTS. в настройках доступен только встроенный монитор и разрешение 640х480. дополнение гостевой ОС устанавливал не помогает. может кто сталкивался? возможно как-то развернуть?

Comment: Вот так ставил? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621928/191416

Comment: @don Rumata попробовал, не помогает

Comment: Может оперативы обычной и видео выставить по-больше?

Comment: @don Rumata, видео на максимум, оператива в половину. Например в 5 версии virtualbox проблемы не наблюдается, но она не совместима с КриптоПРО.

Comment: Что значит не совместима? Хасп не пробрасывается?

Comment: @don Rumata, значит что при установленном криптопро на компьютере, попытка запустить virtualbox вызывает синий экран. например, вот здесь эта проблема изложена http://qapositive.blogspot.ru/2016/01/bsod-virtualbox-5-csp-36-r4.html. из выходов остаться с поддерживаемой версией и добить разрешение.

Comment: А если криптопро поставить в виртуалку? И хасп туда же пробрасывать.

Comment: криптопро на окнах работает, следовательно, чтобы ее поставить на виртуалку нужна лицензия еще и туда (это не домашнее использование).

Comment: А удалисть с хоста и воткнуть в виртуалку не? Или там привязка к железу?

Comment: не вопрос перенести криптопро, вопрос что на локальном компе где она установлена работает винда, а убунта в виртуалке, соответственно чтобы перенести в виртуалку криптопро, нужно завести вторую виртуалку с виндой. и вот тут встает вопрос с лицензией. потому что без лицензии никто мне не даст в коммерческой организации запустить там винду. Не смотря на то, что она нигде не будет светиться. Это уже пройденный этап, когда другому разрабу ставили криптопро(у него на локальной машине линух) ему дали лицензию для виртуалки.